# How to prevent user from leaving view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iPad app (XCode5, ARC, iOS7, Storyboards with a UITabBarController controlling the navigation).  On one view, I have some required fields that I check for in **-viewWillDisappear**; if one of them is missing, I display an alert.  The problem is I need to stay on that view until it's corrected.  Unfortunately, the only place I can check for the required fields is in **-viewWillDisappear**.

Is there some way I can cause the view to complete the disappear and then go back to that same view?  I have looked at SO and it doesn't appear to be a way, but I thought I'd ask anyway, just in case someone has figured out how to do it.. :D

Comment: how do you leave the view? through the pressure of a button? Does the button trigger a segue?

Comment: it is always possible to kill your app from multitask , hopefully

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using a UITabBarController; the user can go from one tab to another... there is no "back" button.  I don't want to "kill" the app, I want to stay on that view until the user corrects the errorl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self
```

in your viewdidload and then implement the delegate method

```
  - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(conditions_satisfied)
        return YES;
    else
    {
        //show alert view here
        return NO;
    }
}
```

EDIT:It would appear that `rdelmar` was faster than me :)

Comment: That's it!  I'll give it a go and get back to you... as I indicated below, after all these years coding in Obj-c, I still don't completely understand Delegates! :-{

Comment: Maybe, but he didn't give me any code to work with... Q: I assume the above code goes into the viewController that is doing the validation for missing fields, yes?

Comment: yea exactly, in addition you'll need to write `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` in order to specify that you're adopting the protocol

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thank you so much for providing the code.  In addition to that, I think I finally understand delegates... :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delegate for the tab bar controller, and return NO from tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: until whatever conditions you set are met.

Comment: That sounds good.. however, delegates are not one of my strong points (been working with Obj-C now for about 2 years, and I just can't get my mind around them).  Let me try once again and I'll get back to you.